# How to solve this integral with a $\Vert x\Vert^2$ in the denominator?

Tags: probability, integration, approximation

I want to evaluate or approximate a lower bound for the following integral,
\begin{eqnarray}
 \int \exp\left[-q(\mathbf{x})-\sum_i \frac{(u_i- \mathbf{v}_i^\mathsf{T}\mathbf{x})^2}{1+c_i \Vert x\Vert^2}\right] d^n\mathbf{x},
\end{eqnarray}
where $x\in \mathbb R^n$; $c_i>0$ and $\mathbf{v}_i\in \mathbb R^n$ are constants; $q(\mathbf{x}) = t\Vert x \Vert^2$, $t\in\mathbb R$;  and $u_i\in  \mathbb R$ are variables which I want to find the integral in terms of.

If there wasn't $\Vert x\Vert^2$ at the denominator of the term inside summation, we can easily solve this integral.

Is there any way to find a the answer to this integral or find a function which lower bound this function ? How do you face such a problem if it show up in your research?
Is there any other choice of $q(\mathbf{x})$ which makes the problem simple?

Is it a good idea to replace the term $(u_i- \mathbf{v}_i^\mathsf{T}\mathbf{x})^2/(1+c_i \Vert x\Vert^2)$ with 
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{(u_i- \mathbf{v}_i^\mathsf{T}\mathbf{x})^2}{1+c_i \Vert x\Vert^2} = (u_i- \mathbf{v}_i^\mathsf{T}\mathbf{x})^2 \left[1-c_i\Vert x\Vert^2+(c_i\Vert x\Vert^2)^2-(c_i\Vert x\Vert^2)^3 +o(\epsilon)\right]
\end{eqnarray}
and if yes, how to continue?

Comment: If $c_i > 0$, you can approximate the fraction as being less than 1.  Or do you need a tighter bound?

Comment: @Paul, Yes $c_i>0$ and also, I need a bound which doesn't ignore the values of $c_i$.

Comment: @user85361 I made some edits to the question to make  it a little more readable. Check if they're equivalent to your problem statement. Also, this appears to be a definite integral over all of $\mathbb R^n$, so I removed the indefinite integration tag.

Comment: @eyeballfrog, Thank you very much for your edits.

Comment: @user85361 so how big are the $c_i$ and $\mathbf{v}_i$? All order unity?

Comment: @eyeballfrog, $0\leq c_i \leq 1$ and $u_i= +1 or u_i=-1$. If this helps. But there is nothing very specific about $v_i$.